# SD Card Security for Windows Mobile using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, security, windows-mobile, sd-card

Is there a way to secure the windows mobile so that it will not accept other SD Card Storage except for the one that is registered on that device? I am thinking that it is possible if I can Get the SD Card Serial Number. How to get Serial Number of Memory Card using VB.net Mobile? I can do this in windows-based app but can't find a way in Windows-Mobile... Need help.

```
            For Each drive As DriveInfo In My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives

                  If drive.IsReady = True AndAlso drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
                      Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
                      Dim oDrive As Scripting.Drive

                      fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

                      oDrive = fso.GetDrive(drive.Name)

                      Dim serialnumber = oDrive.SerialNumber
                   End if

             Next
```

Comment: What code do you have on windows app? Have you tried on mobile? If you have what happened... what errors. There may be a way of adapting.

Comment: Thanks for response Mych. I have updated my post with the code I used in windows app. When I tried it on mobile, I get error in Create Object. I have already added Interop.scripting.dll  in my project...